# Angular 2 import error with RequireJS

Tags: asp.net, typescript, requirejs, visual-studio-2015, angular

I'm unable to import Angular2/core due to the following error:

```
Module name "angular2/core" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

This is my Typescript file:

```
import {Component, View} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
@Component({
          selector: "menu"
})
class MenuComponent {
isActive(path: string) {
    return true
   }
}
bootstrap(MenuComponent);
```

Which is compiled with this configuration:

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/js",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },  
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

This is the compiled Javascript file:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
var __metadata = (this && this.__metadata) || function (k, v) {
if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(k, v);
};
var core_1 = require("angular2/core");
var browser_1 = require("angular2/platform/browser");
var MenuComponent = (function () {
function MenuComponent() {
}
MenuComponent.prototype.isActive = function (path) {
    var page = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === undefined || path === '') {
        path = '';
    }
    var result = path === '' ? path === page[page.length - 1] : page[page.length - 1].indexOf(path) > -1;
    return result;
};
MenuComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        selector: "menu"
    }), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [])
], MenuComponent);
return MenuComponent;
})();
browser_1.bootstrap(MenuComponent);
//# sourceMappingURL=menu.js.map
```

My javascript is imported in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/system.src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/rx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/menu.js"></script>
```

I was wondering what's causing the above error. Since I'm unable to change the Javascript code which is compiled from the Typescript file.

I'm also using **Visual Studio 2015** with **ASP.Net 5**.
I know Angular 2 is still in beta and ASP.Net 5 is still in RC, but I doubt this combination is causing the issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you use two module loaders, RequireJS and SystemJS. See what you included in your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script> <------
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/system.src.js"></script> <------
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/rx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/menu.js"></script>
```

You only need one. For example SystemJS. That's the reason of the message. Both libraries try to load the `angular2/core` module...

**Edit**

If you want to use SystemJS only, you could update your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",  <--------
    "moduleResolution": "node",   <--------
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/js",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },  
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: When I'm not adding RequireJS I'm getting an error saying that "require is not defined".
And after looking at this post https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1559, I added RequireJs.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to change the properties `module` and `moduleResolution` into your `tsconfig.json` file. I updated my answer...

Comment: That seems to have fixed it! Thanks Thierry.